# Installing Selenium/Python Bindings 2.35.0 on Windows7

Tags: python, selenium, windows-7

I am finding many resources for using easy_install and pip to set up the NEWEST version of Selenium on a Windows machine. But how would I do so for a dated version of Selenium? I can get the tar.gz file, but have no idea how or where to put it in relation to C:\python27

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a package manager called [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). Then specify the [specific](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-packages) selenium version using `==`:

```
pip install selenium==2.35.0
```

See also: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)